# Trying to get table to appear slowly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table nested inside of a another tables `<td>`. When a user clicks on that `<td>`'s `<h3>` element I want the nested table to slide down and appear slowly using jQuery. I have it basically working but I'm having an issue with the appearing table. It just appears and doesn't drop down like I'm asking jQuery to do. here is the project site:

Click on the bar that says, "Home Buyer Tips." This is the only item I have the jQuery tied to for now.

[Drop down table](http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/poject.html)

Here is the jQuery i am using:

```
$("h3#homeBuyerTips").click(function() {
    $("#hidden1").slideDown("slow");
```

Here is the CSS for the nested table:

```
#hidden1 {
    display: none;
}
```

And here is the HTML for just the item I am trying to show:

```
<tr>        
  <td colspan="3">
    <h3 id="homeBuyerTips">Home Buyer Tips</h3>
    <table id="hidden1">
      <thead>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Modified</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Home Buyer Tips</td>
        <td class="link" id="version11">
          <a href="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-to-client/homeBuyerTips/homeBuyerTip_email1.html" target="_blank">version 1</a>
        </td>
        <td class="date">02/05/2012</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="link" id="version12">
          <a href="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-to-client/homeBuyerTips/homeBuyerTip_email2.html" target="_blank">version 2</a>
        </td>
        <td class="date">02/05/2012</td>
      </tr>         
      <tr>
        <td class="link" id="version13">
          <a href="http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-to-client/homeBuyerTips/homeBuyerTip_email3.html" target="_blank">version 3</a>
        </td>
        <td class="date">02/06/2012</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="previewTitle"><td colspan="3">Preview</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="previewWindow1" class="previewWindow" colspan="3" style="background: #FFF; height: 250px; width:780px;">
          <h2>Preview Window</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thank you so much in advance. Please let me know if I should post more of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `#hidden1` table in a div and call that `#hidden1` instead.  Table has `display:table`, not `display:block`, therefore it acts differently

Additionally, I'd use `slideToggle()` instead of `slideDown()`  That way you can click it more than once to 'toggle' it up and down.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QCua9/

Comment: Thanks for the additions "slideToggle()" !

Answer (score 3):

I don't think jquery supports animating tables.

[Slide TABLE element](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/qE3TR/) (as your markup - not working)

If you wrap the table #hidden1 inside a DIV element, the slidedown works as expected.

[Wrapped in a DIV](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zyMmY/) (working)